# How to delete multiple activities at the same time in opentaps?

Tags: crm, ofbiz

I am trying to delete multiple activities at the same time in opentaps so I changed the ListPendingActivities form to a multi form and added checkboxes. However when I submit/delete (or try to) the form, I get the error message that the workEffortId is missing. I was under the impression that the service is invoke per each selected row and made the assumption that all values in each row are passed to the service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake. I had copied the service being invoked from the 'per row' delete button into the forms' target instead of calling the request which invoked the service.